androidstudio internal error com.teng.intellij.lua
Internal error. Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com.tang.intellij.lua.project.LuaSettings [Plugin: com.tang]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices2(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:854)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:806)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:403)
    at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.registerComponents(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:58)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$initServiceContainer$2.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:197)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$initServiceContainer$2.invoke(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$initServiceContainer$2.invoke(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span$default(tracer.kt:49)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader.initServiceContainer(ApplicationLoader.kt:196)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader.access$initServiceContainer(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$loadApp$2$initServiceContainerJob$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:86)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Caused by: com.intellij.platform.instanceContainer.internal.InstanceAlreadyRegisteredException: com.tang.intellij.lua.project.LuaSettings
    at com.intellij.platform.instanceContainer.internal.InstanceRegistrarImpl.registerInitializer(InstanceRegistrarImpl.kt:32)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices2Inner(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:910)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices2(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:847)
    ... 20 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android_Studio\jbr

please help me. I uninstalled android studio 3 to 4 times and then reinstalled it but still the same error is occurring. I also asked chatgpt but he said to disable com.teng.intellij.lua but there is no folder or file with this name in my android studio directory and no files or folders with this name are there in my entire system. I hope you understand my problem and help me

Plugins directory located in a different place (c:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioVERSION), not the Android Studio directory itself, see official documentation on Android Studio directories. Most likely you need to remove only plugin itself, but if it will not help you can try to clean all specified paths: Configuration, Plugins, System and Logs.
